# Unusual termination in try catch throw

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, throw

My OS is Win8
using Code::Blocks 12.10

I'm trying to get a handle on throwing and handling exceptions using an 
example from 
Starting Out with C++ Early Objects Addison Wesley.

Here is the simple code I'm using:

```
// This program illustrates exception handling
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

// Function prototype
double divide(double, double);

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    double quotient;

    //cout << "Enter two integers: ";
    //cin >> num1 >> num2;

    num1 = 3;
    num2 = 0;

    try
    {
        quotient = divide(num1,num2);
        cout << "The quotient is " << quotient << endl;
    }
    catch (char *exceptionString)
    {
        cout << exceptionString;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);     // Added to provide a termination.
    }
    cout << "End of program." << endl;
    return 0;
  }

 double divide(double numerator, double denominator)
 {
    if (denominator == 0)
        throw "Error: Cannot divide by zero\n";
    else
        return numerator/denominator;
 }
```

The program will compile, and when I use two ints > 0 execution is normal. If I try to divide by 0 however, I get the following message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Process returned 255 (0xFF)   execution time : 4.485 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I've looked at other examples, but have yet to find similar code to derive an answer from.

Any advice?

Comment: Did you try to catch a `char const*`? (just a wild guess)

Comment: what is the "following message " ?

Comment: I recommend declaring variables closest to first use and initializing them to their value when possible.

Comment: The program runs fine for me in VC11. I get the exception message as output.

Comment: DyP guessed it correctly. Make it an answer.

Comment: @typ1232 I tried a clean and rebuild and get the same message.

Comment: In case you missed Dyp's comment: `throw "message";` throws an instance of `const char*`. You can't catch it with `catch(char*)`. VC11 is wrong to allow it.

Comment: @jrok - prior to C++11 there was an implicit conversion of the type of a string literal to `char*`, so for compilers prior to C++11 the code is valid.

Comment: @PeteBecker but it was deprecated even back then, wasn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a compelling example in the C++ Standard, [except.throw]/1:

> Example:
>
> ```
> throw "Help!";
> ```
>
> can be caught by a *handler* of `const char*` type:
>
> ```
> try {
>     // ...
> } catch(const char* p) {
>     // handle character string exceptions here
> }
> ```

When you throw via `throw "Error: Cannot divide by zero\n";`, the expression after `throw` is a string literal, therefore of type *array of n **const** char* (where *n* is the length of the string + 1). This array type is decayed to a pointer [except.throw]/3, therefore the type of the object thrown is `char const*`.

Which types are catched by a *handler* (`catch`) is described in [except.handle]/3, and none of the cases apply here, i.e. the `const char*` is not catched by a *handler* of type `char*`.

Comment: That's correct for C++11; prior to C++11 there was an implicit type conversion from a string literal to `char*`, and the code was valid.

Comment: Yes, it was deprecated, but that doesn't mean it wasn't part of the language. Deprecated means **only** that it **might** go away in the future. Use of C-style headers is deprecated, but they won't ever go away, despite the fantasies of some of the people in the earlier days of standardization.

Comment: Yeah I didn't mean to say it was disallowed. It just should have already been avoided to use it, even when it still was legal in C++03.

Comment: Yup; I would never write that catch clause without a `const`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Upon further investigation of the C++03 Standard, isn't the conversion that was legal from *array to n const char* to *pointer to char*, and not a pointer conversion?

Comment: @Pete Becker: Even though there was such a conversion in pre C++11 language, it did not apply to `throw/catch` situations. Even in C++98 `catch (char *)` was not allowed to catch string literals. `throw "test"` throws a `const char *` value and at that point the fact that it was obtained from string literal is completely forgotten. It has never been not possible to catch that value by `catch (char *)` in C++.

Comment: @PeterBecker C++03: "Note: the temporary object created for a *throw-expression* that is a string literal is never of type `char*` or `wchar_t*`; that is, the special conversions for string literals from the types *array of const `char`* and *array of const `wchar_t`* to the types *pointer to `char`* and *pointer to `wchar_t`*, respectively (4.2), are never applied to a throw-expression. " [except.throw]/3

Comment: Yes. The type that was thrown is `array of N const char`; I haven't worked through the details of array to pointer conversions here, but I assume that the code worked as written because otherwise (<g>) it wouldn't have been published.

Comment: @DyP - re: the quote: right, but that's the `throw` expression, so the type of the object thrown is `array of N const char`; at the point of the `catch` it gets converted.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'd say no, because same paragraph: "A throw-expression initializes a temporary object, called the exception object, the type of which is determined by removing any top-level cv-qualifiers from the static type of the operand of throw **and adjusting the type from “array of T” or “function returning T” to “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T”, respectively**."

Comment: @Pete Becker: No, arrays are never thrown as arrays. Arrays decay to pointers immediately, at the point of the `throw`.